# How to apply a filter on date fields in UltraEdit

Tags: date, filter, ultraedit

I am trying to use the filter option in UltraEdit. I have a simple CSV file. It has 3 columns. The last column has dates. I need to apply a filter so that I see only those lines with dates older than, say, 05/01/2019.

```
24.59,000000024.13,06/01/2019
18.45,000000000.00,07/01/2019
18.45,000000018.36,07/01/2019
94.08,000000000.00,02/01/2019
19.83,000000000.00,02/01/2019
77.35,000000000.00,02/01/2019
51.22,000000000.00,02/01/2019
14.02,000000000.00,02/01/2019
70.21,000000000.00,02/01/2019
25.24,000000000.00,02/01/2019
17.35,000000000.00,02/01/2019
```

Is there a way to do that in UltraEdit in column-mode or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by moving caret to top of file with <kbd>Ctrl+Home</kbd> and opening regular **Find** window for example with <kbd>Alt+F3</kbd> (default key assignment) and

- enter as search string `(?:19\d\d|200[0-9]|201[0-8]|0[1-4]/01/2019)$`,
- select *Current file* for option *In*,
- click on gearwheel button to show advanced find options if not already visible,
- check the option *Regular expressions* and select *Perl*,
- check the option *Filter lines* and select *Show*,
- check the option *Close after find*,
- uncheck all other check boy options,
- click on button **Next** to run the find and hide all lines matching the Perl regular expression search string.

The Perl regular expression search string matches the years `1900` to `1999` **OR** the years `2000` to `2009` **OR** the years `2010` to `2018` **OR** the dates `01/01/2019` to `04/01/2019` which must be found at end of a line for a positive match.

Well, it is unclear if the date format is `DD/MM/YYYY` (British) or `MM/DD/YYYY` (U.S.). So the line hiding can be correct or wrong depending on date format and what is meant with **older than 05/01/2019**. I assume the format `DD/MM/YYYY` as today is `2019-05-05` (international date format YYYY-MM-DD) and so `06/01/2019` would be a date in future on being `MM/DD/YYYY`.

The same can be also achieved by searching with Perl regular expression for

```
(?:0[5-9]/01/2019|[1-3]\d/\d\d/2019|\d\d/0[2-9]/2019|\d\d/1[0-2]/2019)$
```

matching the dates `05/01/2019` to `09/01/2019` **OR** any date with first digit of day being `1` to `3` in year `2019` **OR** any date with month `02` to `09` in year `2019` **OR** any date with month `10` to `12` in year `2019` found at end of line with using *Hide* instead of *Show* as filter option for *Filter lines*.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I should have been explicit about the date format. It is MM/DD/YYYY. So, based on the example I pasted, I should be getting all the February rows.